# 24hrs running service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.Net mvc 3 C# to make a web application. I have some service that needs to be running in an interval of x minutes. Also, some settings could be updated or changed for this service.

I am not sure, what technology i should use to keep my service running on the server and to be able to stop it/run it remotely using the ASP.Net MVC interface (web).

I assume some hidden service or application that has a timer to fire the required job every x minutes.

Any suggestions as it is my first big .Net project :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what control you have over the environment you deploy to. If it is your server and you have sufficient privileges over it, you can either:

1. Write a Windows service that has a timer in it, which wakes up and executes an Http request on your web app.
2. Set up a scheduled task that runs a VB script (or similar) to call your web app.

One thing I would not recommend doing is using a background thread in your web app that has a timer on it. You can do that ([http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+haacked+%28you%27ve+been+HAACKED%29](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20haacked%20%28you%27ve%20been%20HAACKED%29)) but it is inherently unsafe if the web's app domain is brought down.

If you are deploying to an ISP, shared hosting, or for some reason you can only deploy your web app and nothing else, you will need to have a script that runs elsewhere that calls the web app. Most ISP's, even on shared hosting, will let you set up a scheduled task. You can then upload a simple VB script to cgi-bin, for example, which calls the web app (http://chriscant.phdcc.com/2011/05/scheduled-task-ping-for-plesk-in.html).

I am just about to implement the last solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) as the site says "Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems."

Answer (score 0):

if you have the dedicated server, you can go with the windows service. Else we can create the webservice. This webservice will be called from the timer, which will fire automatically at the particular time interval. and this timer is needed to be started under the application_start event specified over the global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the application that needs to run every x minutes a console application that reads it settings from an XML file or database. The settings can then be adjusted in your Asp.NET MVC application.
You will also need a windows service that runs all the time to start the console application every x minutes. Also the interval and maybe an enabled property can be set via the Asp.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a console as already suggested. However, your query is more around how to operationalize it. Does your customer have any sort of scheduler. Typically schedulers have their own web interace or API's that allows you to manage operational aspects.

Refer here if you want to invoke [Windows Services via .Net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1062574.aspx/1)